# Populate tableview with Facebook Friends

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The idea is to fill an array of strings with IDs of Facebook Friends (from Graph request), then search the (Firebase) database for those IDs (as children) and, finally, populate the tableview with the relevant data (username, image) read from the database.
This is why I tried:

```
let params = ["fields": "id"]

    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: params, httpMethod: "GET")
    let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
    connection.add(request, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")
        } else {
            if let userData = result as? [String:Any] {
                let data: NSArray = userData["data"] as! NSArray
                for i in  0..<data.count {
                    let dict = data[i] as! NSDictionary
                    let temp = dict.value(forKey: "id") as! String
                    // temp is an ID of a Facebook friend
                    self.ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "fbid").queryEqual(toValue: temp).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        if snapshot.exists() {
                            let snap = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                            self.usersArray.append(snap?["username"] as! String)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            //tableview is obviously populated with usersAray
                        }
                    })

                }
            }
        }
    })
    connection.start()
```

without luck. I hope there are better and faster ways to accomplish the goal. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks ok and appears to work so one modification would be to reload the tableView after the array is populated instead of each time through - that would prevent flicker. You'll have to do it asynchronously so the table update  occurs after the loading of the data. It won't speed it up really but it's unclear from the question what part is 'slow'

Another option would be to load the /users node by .value into an array and look  up the fbid via that array instead of hitting Firebase over and over. That solution may/may not be viable depending on the number of users.

A super cool option would be to have a separate node with just the Facebook id's and the user names. So if your users node looks like this

```
/users
   uid_0
     fbid: "fbid_1"
     name: "Pete"
   uid_1
     fbid: "fbid_2"
     name: "George"
```

have another node that provides direct access to the data you want instead of running a query.

```
/lookup
   fbid_1: "Pete"
   fbid_2: "George"
```

that would greatly simplify your loading code - something like this

```
for i in  0..<data.count {
    let fbid = data[i]
    let userRef = self.ref.child("lookup").child(fbid)
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let name = snapshot.value as! String
        usersArray.append(name)
    })
}
```

Firebase queries are 'heavier' than directly accessing a node and if you are doing a lot of that directly loading the node and avoiding a query can speed up access.

Comment: Thank you Jay, your idea seems as the best solution. However, I don't understand why my question got downvoted. Nevertheless, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @NedimKurbegović Glad it helped! I don't know why it was down voted and got a close vote! You described the issue, presented code as to what you tried and provided other info. The only thing I can think of is that a snippet of your Firebase structure was not included. It's been upvoted now.

Comment: One more quick question. I want to get data from users/username, so below usersArray.append(name) is it a good idea to write: self.ref.child("users").child("username") and observe a single event and save it as a dictionary? Is this nesting references harmless?

Comment: @NedimKurbegović That would work but remember everything happens asynchronously so need to account for that in the UI. Optionally, you can store the data you need in that node as well - duplicating data is common practice in NoSQL databases. So if you wanted the user name and age, replace the value (currently a string) with another snapshot (dict) with name: "users name" and age: "50".